# plt.show() from matplotlib does not open a window

Tags: python, linux, matplotlib, ssh, conda

I know this question or a related one has been asked many times, but I still have not found a solution: I ssh -X into a linux machine, where I run a conda installation of ipython. After importing matplotlib, I generate a plot (e.g., `plt.plot(1,1)`) and I want to show the plot in a window, which is forwarded to my local machine with `plt.show()`. This used to work, but suddenly no longer does: plt.show() does nothing. I guess this is related to a conda update, which I did yesterday, since a `conda list --revisions` does not show any suspicious recent changes in my environment.

From similar posts, I guess this is related to the matplotlib backend. The default backend 'Agg' generates png's via plt.savefig, but does not produce a plot in its own window, in which I can zoom. I have not managed to change the backend, though:

```
In [7]: import tkinter
In [8]: import matplotlib
In [9]: matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
In [10]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

gives

```
ImportError: Cannot load backend 'TkAgg' which requires the 'tk' interactive framework, as 'headless' is currently running
```

I have tried various similar things but with no success. Any suggestions?

Thank you!